# Как можно собрать запрос в Eloquent из имеющегося запроса MySQL

Tags: база-данных, laravel

Хай, подскажите пожалуйста
в Laravel всегда рекомендуют использовать Eloquent ORM и стараться меньше пользоваться QUeryBuilder'ом и/или прямыми вставками SQL'ских запросов. Якобы это правило хорошего тона разработчика в Laravel.

Вопрос: как можно заменить

```
SELECT `tasks`.`title`, `tasks`.`link`, `users`.`name` FROM `tasks` 
JOIN `pivot_task_group` ON `tasks`.`id` = `pivot_task_group`.`task_id`
JOIN `users` ON `tasks`.`author_id` = `users`.`id`
ORDER BY `tasks`.`created_at` DESC
```

на запрос Eloquent и добавить пагинацию по 5 task на стрнице:

```
$tasks = Task::all()->publishedTasks()->paginate(5);
```

или так

```
$tasks = $tasks->publishedTasks()->paginate(5);
```

или как?

```
...
```

Имеется:
    сlass Task extends Model
    {
        //
        use SoftDeletes;

```
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Group', 'pivot_task_group');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment');
    }

    public function getPublishedTasks(){
        return $this->belongToMany('Group', 'pivot_task_group');
    }

    public static function author(){
        return $this->belongTo('User');
    }
}
```

И модели `User`,`Group`.

Вот что ожидаю в получить в ответе:
[image: скрин ответа запроса из phpmyadmin]
чтобы можно было обращаться
    foreach ($tasks as $task)
    {
    echo $task->title;
    echo $task->link;
    echo $task->author->name;
    }

Буду ждать Ваших рекомендаций. и заранее благодарю за все советы и булыжники.)))

Answer (score 1):

кое что разобрал:
для того чтобы вытащить имена пользователей по `author_id` делаю так:

в модели `Task` пишу

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

а в коде где у меня будет объект-задача (не задачи) обращаюсь так

```
$tasks= Task::with('author')->get();
```

Вопрос с привязкой снят, осталось понять как делать:

```
SELECT 'tasks'.'title', 'tasks'.'link' FROM 'tasks' 
JOIN 'pivot_task_group' ON 'tasks'.'id' = 'pivot_task_group'.'task_id' 
GROUP BY 'pivot_task_group'.'task_id'
ORDER BY 'tasks'.'created_at' DESC
```

Кстати добавилась группировка по `task_id` потому что опубликованные задачи в пивоте могут повторяться, а любая одна задача назначаться разным группам.